# Remove double quotation from write statement in vba

Tags: vba, excel

This code will write log file to LogFilePath, and generate output as below. StarRange and EndRange is a variable which value will populate from other function.

```
"Start postion",A1
"End position",B100

---Code-----------------
Sub WriteLogFile()
 Dim FilePath As String

 LogFilePath = WriteTextBox.Text

LogFilePath = LogFilePath & ".log"
Open LogFilePath For Output As #2

Write #2, "Start postion"; StarRange
Write #2, "End position"; EndRange
Close #2

MsgBox FinalFileName

End Sub
```

My question is how can I remove double quotation mark from output and produce output as below. Thanks

```
Start position = A1
End position = B100
```

Comment: What is `StaRrange` - a named ranged?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`Write` is a special statement designed to generate machine-readable files that are later consumed with `Input`.

Use `Print` to avoid any fiddling with data.

```
Print #2, "Start postion = "; StarRange
Print #2, "End position = "; EndRange
```

Comment: Works for CSV file exports as well. Thanks.