# When csv file is save as plain text it will generate " " between each cell of excel

Tags: excel, csv, office-2007

I am having simple excel sheet when I save as it as a textfile it is giving "" format

For example

csv is

```
1st cell  2nd cell 
akshay,   shah,
```

note : , is not the separater it is complete one value

when I save it as a text it is giving

```
"akshay," "shah,"
```

I need below output

```
akshay, shah,
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving a Excel File into .txt format without quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501531/saving-a-excel-file-into-txt-format-without-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

The double-quotes are there to "protect" the commas when the file is re-opened in Excel.

To save without the double-quotes, save in **.prn** format.