# Export each row of spreadsheet to separated .txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I've a spreadsheet with 500 rows and 4 columns. I want to save each row to a separated TXT file and separate each column of rows by comma.

an example is :

```
spreadsheet data:

column1 column2 column3 column4

 id     title    body   personid

txt file : (should be)

id,title,body,personid
```

for each row.

Comment: Please let us know what had you tried.

Comment: You may refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501531/saving-a-excel-file-into-txt-format-without-quotes

Comment: No, it was not i need to. I want save each row in separated txt file. I can convert one column to txt file but i can'nt convert  a row by multiple column to a txt file

Comment: This can be easily achieved with out VBA, is it necessary that you use some code. (if it is one time activity - then code is not required.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub SaveWorksheet()
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyDataWorksheet As Worksheet

Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyDataWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim OutputFile As String
Dim CellValue As String
Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim CurrentCol As Long
Dim CurrentCharacter As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MyString As String

LastRow = MyDataWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow
'C:\Users\lengkgan\Desktop\Testing\sample.txt
OutputFile = "C:\Users\lengkgan\Desktop\Testing\sample" & CurrentRow & ".txt"

Open OutputFile For Output As #1

    CellValue = MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value & "," & MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Value & "," & MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Value & "," & MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Value
    'Write #1, CellValue
    Print #1, CellValue

Close #1

Next CurrentRow

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```