# Double Quotes issue in VBA vbNewLine

Tags: excel, vba

Code :

```
var1 = "Hello"
var2 = "Dear"
var3 = var1 & vbNewLine & var2

Sheets("sheet_name").Cells(1, 1).Value = var3
```

If we take cell value in text file it looks like..

"Hello
Dear"

I do not want double quotes surrounding the text.Could anyone suggest me for this issue.

Comment: It's because of your line break.  Why not just wrap the text instead?
`Sheets("sheet_name").Cells(1, 1).WrapText = True`

Comment: When you "save as text", the quotes are inserted to indicate the `Cell Value` wraps onto multiple lines. What do you prefer to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving a Excel File into .txt format without quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501531/saving-a-excel-file-into-txt-format-without-quotes)

Comment: @laylarenee I don't think it is a duplicate of that.  That is saving the file.  This is adding a value with a new line, then even if you just copy the cell contents and paste it to a text file it adds the double quotes.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your code though. Your code is fine. If you wrote in a cell, manually: `Hello <Alt+Enter> Dear` and copy and pasted that into a text file you would get quotes.

Comment: The quotation marks are being added when you "save as text file". I think that article is relevant.