# Excel VBA Save as tab delimited file

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that saves the active worksheet as a tab delimited text file, however the cell data that has a comma character in them gets exported with quotation marks, like

```
John Hopkins, Burgers
becomes
"John Hopkins, Burgers"
```

How can I work around this?

This is my code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & filename,
FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

Adding this:
I just found out that if I save the file again it removes all "".
Can I add an additional save to the code?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501531/saving-a-excel-file-into-txt-format-without-quotes

Comment: How do I find and replace a text file from within excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it! Since the quotes disappear when you save it manually as a delimited file but not when you use

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & filename,
FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

I just added another save after the above one, but this time using the sendkey strokes to mimick the manual method.

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fil, FileFormat:= _
        xlText

```
SendKeys "^{F4}"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: If it's important for anyone to not lose formatting or other features of the original workbook, you could also use VBA to create a new workbook, copy over the sheet in question, then export that workbook and close it without saving - thereby giving you the exported text file while leaving your original workbook intact. I do this when I have a workbook with macros and multiple sheets used to populate the CSV sheet that I want. I export that sheet, but leave my working file as is.

Answer (score 1):

According to FileFormat Property, you have the following formats to choose from:

```
xlCSV
xlCSVMac
xlCSVMSDOS
xlCSVWindows
```

Why don't you choose one of the comma- separated value formats?

Try `xlCSV`.

Comment: I tried all of them, none produces the result I want.

Comment: Is it possible to read in that text file and do a simple search and replace to remove all ", marks?

Comment: it still produces ""

Comment: please share file with sample data and the code you have written?

Comment: Yes, we could replace double quotes(").

Answer (score 1):

Change FileFormat xlText  to xlTextPrinter

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & filename,
    FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Makes a real mess ignoring all but the strings in formula.

Comment: After a long time looking for a way to save as a text file without quotation marks, xlTextPrinter worked fine for me and is a great deal simpler than the accepted method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation Of some code I used to save a normal xlsb file or xls* file 
could be used for many different files though.

```
Sub SaveAsTDV()

'
' Easy way to export to Tab Deliminated Values
' By DeLaguna
' v17.05.10.15.06
'

Dim BaseFolder As String
    Dim LitProg As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Extn As String
      BaseFolder = "YourBase Folder\"    
      FileName = "FileName" 'File name with no Extension.
      Extn = ".txt" 'If choosing somthing other than xlText you may change this.

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Auto Yes to save

    ChDir BaseFolder
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= BaseFolder & FileName & Extn, _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=True  'xlText will save as Tab Deliminated text

Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' Reverts to Excel Default showing popup messages for input.

End Sub
```

Hopefully it helps someone let me know if I made any errors I had to redact sensitive information out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to get this working, and found that `xlText` isn't a valid `FileFormat` but `xlTextWindows` is. This might be version related, but just in case anybody else has the same issue.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & filename,FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, reateBackup:=False
```

A full list of valid entries for `FileFormat` is held here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat