# Saveas surrounding text with double quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that saves data to an external file.  It uses this command:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Filename, FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False`

My problem is that most of the data that has been saved is surrounded by double quotes.  But few pages are saved **without** the double quotes.

It is the same macro that saves the data so why do some files not have the double quotes?  How can I make all pages save without double quotes?

**UPDATE:**

Every cell in every sheet contains commas.  The data in Excel cells is not surrounded by double quotes.  I use Excel to build SQL queries.  But, some of the sheets still save to file **without** double quotes.  What sheet setting should I look for, if any?

Comment: When you save as `FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText`, any text which has comma will be surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501531/saving-a-excel-file-into-txt-format-without-quotes

Comment: @SiddharthRout, thanks for the reply.  Please see my update in the question.

Comment: Did you go through the link that I posted above? Because that has your solution

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Yes, but I don't want another macro to fix the problem.  Excel does what I want I just need to figure out why it works both ways with 1 macro.   I will re-read the article again.  Thanks for your input.