# Export file to text file without quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export my workbook to a text file but my code adds quotes in the exported file if the cells has commas in it.

Below is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub ExportFile()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim saveFile As String
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim r As Long

    On Error Resume Next
  

    r = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set WorkRng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(r, 99))


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add

    WorkRng.Copy

    wb.Worksheets(1).Paste

    saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="output", fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

    wb.Close

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Current Output:
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlx7l.png)

Desired Output:
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8RFT.png)

Comment: This is the expected behavior, because each cell is represented as comma-delimited values. What do you expect the output to look like and can you provide a simple example?

Comment: @PeterT I was hoping to export it to a text file without quotes. Just added an example of my current output and my desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving a Excel File into .txt format without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501531/saving-a-excel-file-into-txt-format-without-quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the answers in the link posted in comments above will provide a good solution. For me personally, I most often want a bit more control over the output and usually code my own solution. You choose your own path.... :)

> EDIT: added code to delete the "hanging" delimiter on the end of each line, and the "hanging" vbNewLine at the end of the whole buffer.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportThisSheet()
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Set thisWS = Sheet1
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim workArea As Range
    With thisWS
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set workArea = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 99))
    End With
        
    Const DELIMITER As String = vbTab   'change to "    " ?
    Dim workRow As Variant
    Dim textLine As String
    Dim textResult As String
    For Each workRow In workArea.Rows
        textLine = vbNullString
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To workArea.Columns.Count
            '--- optionally check if the Value is empty and skip if you want
            textLine = textLine & workRow.Cells(1, i).Value & DELIMITER
        Next i
        '--- delete the extra DELIMITER
        textLine = Left$(textLine, Len(textLine) - 1)
        textResult = textResult & textLine & vbNewLine
    Next workRow
    '--- delete the last newline
    textResult = Left$(textResult, Len(textResult) - 1)
        
    Dim saveFilename As String
    saveFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="output", _
                                                  FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    Open saveFilename For Output As #1
    Print #1, textResult
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. This exports it without the quotes but it now adds an extra column at the end and also a blank row at the end than the specified range. Any ideas ?

Comment: See the revised code above

Comment: Thank you Peter! Much Appreciated!